# How to remove the warnings from libraries included from POD

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have included the RETableview manager library from POD. I need to remove the warnings currently I am getting. What are the best ways of receiving the updates

Comment: what warning is it ?

Comment: Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'onBeginEditing'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention

Answer (score 2):

You can use surpress a lot of warning generated from clang from either build options or in your code. For instance, if you had a unused variable you didn't want to keep getting warned about, you could do this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"

let a = 1;

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

The basic idea is to edit compiler diagnostics and then restore them. When your source file is compiled it will basically ignore that line from a diagnostic perspective. You can do a lot more with the pragma marks as well, check out clang's user [manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I basically do not want to modify files that are generated from pod.

Comment: The warnings are not going to magically disappear unfortunately ;-)